# T-SQL generate sequence from string and count

Tags: t-sql, csv

I need to generate a sequence starting from a CSV string and a maximum count.
When the sequence exceed, I need to start the sequence again and continue until I saturate the COUNT variable

I have the following CSV:

```
A,B,C,D
```

In order to get 4 rows out of this CSV I am using XML and the following statement:

```
    SET @xml_csv = N'<root><r>' + replace('A, B, C, D',',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>'                   
    SELECT
        REPLACE(t.value('.','varchar(max)'), ' ', '') AS [delimited items]
    FROM 
        @xml_csv.nodes('//root/r') AS a(t)
```

Now my SELECT returns the following output:

```
|-------------|
| A           |
| B           |
| C           |
| D           |
```

Assuming I have a @count variable set to 9, I need to output the following:

```
|--|-----------|
|1 |A          |
|2 |B          |
|3 |C          |
|4 |D          |
|5 |A          |
|6 |B          |
|7 |C          |
|8 |D          |
|9 |A          |
```

I tried to join a table called master..[spt_values] but I get for a COUNT = 10 10 rows for A, 10 for B and so on, while I need the sequence ordered and repeated until it saturate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are on the correct path. Joining the split result with a numbers table will get you the correct output.

I've chosen to use a different function for splitting the csv data since it's using a numbers table for the split as well. (taken from [this great article](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings))

First, if you don't already have a numbers table, create one. here is the script used in the article I've linked to:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @UpperLimit INT = 1000;

WITH n AS
(
    SELECT
        x = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
    FROM       sys.all_objects AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s3
)
SELECT Number = x
  INTO dbo.Numbers
  FROM n
  WHERE x BETWEEN 1 AND @UpperLimit;

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX n ON dbo.Numbers(Number) 
    WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE);
GO
```

Then, create the split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_Numbers
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN
   (
       SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
         CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)
       FROM dbo.Numbers
       WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
         AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, LEN(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter
   );
GO
```

Next step: Join the split results with the numbers table:

```
DECLARE @Csv varchar(20) = 'A,B,C,D'

SELECT TOP 10 Item
FROM dbo.SplitStrings_Numbers(@Csv, ',')
CROSS JOIN Numbers
ORDER BY Number
```

Output:

```
Item
----
A
B
C
D
A
B
C
D
A
B
```

Great thanks to [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) for sharing his knowledge.

Comment: So I was almost there, except the last part :-)
I have the same number table, But I couldn't figure out the CROSS JOIN
Thanks, it works

Comment: Yeah, you where very close... Glad to help :-)